# PHP: how to check if a given file has been included() inside a function

Tags: php, php-include

I have a PHP file that can be include'd() in various places inside another page. I want to know whether it has been included inside a function. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a function called [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) that will return the current call stack as an array. It feels like a somewhat ugly solution but it'll probably work for most cases:

```
$allowedFunctions = array('include', 'include_once', 'require', 'require_once');
foreach (debug_backtrace() as $call) {
    // ignore calls to include/require
    if (isset($call['function']) && !in_array($call['function'], $allowedFunctions)) {
        echo 'File has not been included in the top scope.';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable in the included file and check for that variable in your functions:

include.php:

```
$included = true;
```

anotherfile.php:

```
function whatever() {
    global $included;

    if (isset($included)) {
        // It has been included.
    }
}

whatever();
```

Comment: I thought of that, but the file in question is included in many many other places, and I'm afraid that a variable with the same name might be defined somewhere else before the included file (the code I'm working on is such a mess that it wouldn't surprise me). Isn't there any feature built into the language for this?

Comment: Just give that variable `$a_really_special_unique_name = true`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file is in the array returned by get_included_files(). (Note that list elements are full pathnames.) To see if inclusion occurred during a particular function call, check get_included_files before and after the function call.